# Xcode simulator on. Jenkins space crashes automated tests due to audio engine

Tags: ios, swift, jenkins, xcode10, audiokit

I have a swift app that has automated tests, a few of which trigger sounds for different things.  They run fine on my local machine in a simulator and on a real device.

On our Jenkins machine which spins off slave nodes for each build, the tests that trigger audio crash.  The root cause seems to that AvAudioPlayerNode fails due to the engine not running.

[avae] AVAEInternal.h:70:_AVAE_Check: required condition is false: [AVAudioPlayerNode.mm:536:StartImpl: (_engine->IsRunning())]

This worked fine in iOS 11.2 and Xcode 9.  We've just got our Jenkins machine and code updated for iOS 12 and Xcode 10.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way the simulator is handling pass through from the microphone on the computer into the virtual microphone has changed in Xcode10. Jenkins and Travis computers often are virtual machines without a microphone at all.

Comment: You may be right.  Here we're talking audio output, not input.  Before upgrading to Xcode 10, the tests ran fine.  We've logged into the console on the VM and the simulator only has "system" as an audio output hardware option but I think it really has nothing at all.

Comment: For what its worth, we use Travis for our testing, and the way we make sure things "sound" the same is to run on an MD5 on the audio data while its still a buffer in memory and hence actual audio hardware is not required.